# UILocalNotification firedate as fixed time for every day

Tags: iphone, datetime, uilocalnotification

I want to set `firedate` of `UILocalNotification` to 11:00 AM and 11:00 PM every day (Meaning every 12 hours). How can I achieve this? Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Create two seperate [UILocalNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit) and specify the repeat interval.

```
enum {
   NSEraCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitEra,
   NSYearCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitYear,
   NSMonthCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
   NSDayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitDay,
   NSHourCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitHour,
   NSMinuteCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMinute,
   NSSecondCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
   NSWeekCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
   NSWeekdayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday,
   NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal,
   NSQuarterCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter,
   NSCalendarCalendarUnit = (1 << 20),
   NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit = (1 << 21),
};
typedef NSUInteger NSCalendarUnit;
```